# I have question about transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-circuits

When we describe the working principle of the transformer, we say that we want to minimize the loss of electrical energy, therefore we reduce the current Q=I^2Rt, so heat reduces as well, but to keep the same power we increase the voltage, but Q=U^2/R *t. so why voltage doesn't give us the heat effect.

Comment: Short answer: The power transferred depends on the voltage across the load, but the heat generated in the wire depends on the voltage between the two ends of the wire. The transformer increases the first one but reduces the second one (because the current through the wire is reduced).

Comment: that answer helped me can I accept that but wait for other answers as well?  so if we have less current, we have less voltage drop U=IR, so less heat ?

Comment: You can't accept it because it's a comment, not an answer. You can upvote the answer on the previous question (or on the even earlier question on the same topic linked from there).

Comment: So less current means less voltage drop on the wire using Ohm's law, so we have less heat? Am I correct?

Comment: yes, correct....

Comment: Q=U^2/R * t what U is in this formula ?

Comment: U is the voltage across the resistor (wire in the case of the power transmission problem) that you want to work out how much heat it is generating.

Comment: but if we increase U, we get more heat, don't we?

Comment: When you use the transformer, you increase $U_l$ (the voltage across the load), not $U_w$ (the voltage across the wire). The $U$ in the formula for heat generated by the wire is $U_w$, not $U_l$.

Comment: understood everything, thank you very much <3